# How to fix the “Computed output size would be negative” error in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, dqn

I’m trying to train a DQN agent using TensorFlow and Keras, but I get this error when I run my code:
 `2023-04-08 14:38:11.123638: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops.cc:530 : Invalid argument: Computed output size would be negative: -1 [input_size: 1, effective_filter_size: 3, stride: 1]  Traceback (most recent call last):  File “e:/Code/StardrewValleyFishingBot/Main.py”, line 105, in <module> agent.train(state,action,reward,next_state,done)  File “e:\Code\StardrewValleyFishingBot\model.py”, line 32, in train current_q = self.online_net(states)  File “D:\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py”, line 985, in call outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)  File “D:\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py”, line 372, in call return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)`

I think the problem is related to the convolutional layers in my online_net model, but I don’t know how to fix it. Here is the code for my model:

```
class DoubleDQN:
    def __init__(self, input_shape, output_size):
        # Create the online network
        self.online_net = models.Sequential()
        self.online_net.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(36,567,1))
        self.online_net.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
        self.online_net.add(layers.Flatten())
        self.online_net.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
        self.online_net.add(layers.Dense(output_size,activation='linear'))

        # self.online_net.summary()

        # Create the target network
        self.target_net = models.clone_model(self.online_net)
        self.target_net.set_weights(self.online_net.get_weights())

        # Define the optimizer and loss function
        self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00025)
        self.loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.Huber()
```

```
def get_state(screen):
    grayScreen=cv2.cvtColor(screen,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grayScreen_roi=roi(grayScreen,x=55+11,x_w=90+12,y=25,y_h=592) #36 x 567 x 1
    grayScreen_roi=tf.convert_to_tensor(grayScreen_roi)
    grayScreen_roi=tf.reshape(grayScreen_roi,(36,567,1))
    return grayScreen_roi
```

New bing suggested me change the filter size of the first convolutional layer to (2, 2) to avoid negative output dimensions, but it was still wrong.